# Mongoid/MongoDB: Order a query by the value of an embedded document?

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I am attempting to order the results of a query by the value of a specific embedded document, but even with what seems to be a valid set of options and using the `$elemMatch` operator, my results are coming back in natural order.

My model is composed of Cards, which `embeds_many :card_attributes`, which in turn reference a specific CardAttributeField and contain an Integer `value`.  I would like to be able to order a collection of Cards by that value.

I am able to isolate a collection of Cards which have a CardAttribute referencing a specific CardAttributeField like this:

```
cards = Card.where(:card_attributes.elem_match => {
    :card_attribute_field_id => card_attribute_field.id
})
```

If I knew the order in which the card_attributes were set, I could use [MongoDB array notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#match-a-field-in-the-embedded-document-using-the-array-index), like this:

```
cards.order_by(['card_attributes.0.value', :asc])
```

This does deliver my expected results in test scenarios, but it won't work in the real world.

After much messing around, I found a syntax which I thought would allow me to [match a field without using array notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#match-a-field-without-specifying-array-index):

```
cards.asc(:'card_attributes.value'.elem_match => {
    :card_attribute_field_id => card_attribute_field.id
})
```

This produced a set of `options` on the resulting Mongoid::Criteria which looked like:

```
  {:sort=>{"{#<Origin::Key:0x2b897548 @expanded=nil, @operator=\"$elemMatch\", @name=:\"card_attributes.value\", @strategy=:__override__, @block=nil>=>{:card_attribute_field_id=>\"54c6c6fe2617f55611000068\"}}"=>1}}
```

However, the results here came back in the same order regardless or whether I called `asc()` or `desc()`.

Is there any way to do what I'm after?  Am I taking the wrong approach, or do I have a mistake in my implementation?  Thanks.

Simplified, my model is:

```
class Card
  include Mongoid::Document

  # various other fields

  has_many :card_attribute_fields
  embeds_many :card_attributes do
    def for_attribute_field card_attribute_field
      where(:card_attribute_field_id => card_attribute_field.id)
    end
  end
end

class CardAttributeField
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :card

  field :name, type: String
  field :default_value, type: String
  field :description, type: String
end

class CardAttribute
  include Mongoid::Document

  embedded_in :card

  field :card_attribute_field_id, type: Moped::BSON::ObjectId
  field :value, type: Integer
end
```